# Sticky and scrollable Sidebar sidebar - CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, scroll, sidebar, sticky

I am working on a Shopify Store but I would like to make a this sidebar sticky and scrollable. The reaso to be scrollable is that when using the `position: sticky;` css callout the sidebar appears to be very big so it is not visible until the end of the page, then at that moment I would love to make it scrollable so we can filter without having to go to the bottom of the page. I have found something like `overflow-y: scroll;` but does not work together with the sticky thing. I am sharing some example pics: [IMAGE HERE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncjIH.jpg) [IMAGE HERE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaV2W.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to add max-height property to the sticky element
like so

```css
.side-nav{
  position: sticky;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

now your sidenav has a max-height of the height of your screen, so it can apply the scroll behavior if the content is larger than the container